# Пользовательские элементы: Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, html5

Как создать свой пользовательский элемент с рабочим функционалом?

Например хочу чтоб при добавке

```
 <my-timer>0</my-timer>
```

в HTML работал секундомер.

Как можно реализовать это? Ведь в angular.js таким образом по моему работают директивы.Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это делается с помощью document.registerElement и object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)

```
<script>
    var MyTimerProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    MyTimerProto.tick = function() {
        this.timer++;
        this.innerHTML = this.timer;
    };

    MyTimerProto.createdCallback = function() {
        this.timer = 0;
    };

    MyTimerProto.attachedCallback = function() {
        setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
    };

    document.registerElement("my-timer", {
        prototype: MyTimerProto
    });
</script>

<my-timer id="timer">0</my-timer>
```

[Пользовательские элементы: Custom Elements](https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core)

Comment: Спасибо.Javascript рулит :)